# Sync Framework 2.1 SqlSyncProvider/SqlSyncScopeProvisioning retention period

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

This seems like a rather simple question, but I'm having difficulty finding an answer.  When provisioning a SQL database (express or standard) use the Sync Framework SqlSyncScopeProvisioning object there is no way to specify how long changes should be retained (like in SQL Change Tracking).  My question is how do you change the length of time changes are kept and where would one look to see what the current setting is at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're after metadata cleanup/retention, check out the SqlSyncStoreMetadataCleanup api : [SqlSyncStoreMetadataCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617373.aspx)

Comment: I was hoping for something more automated, but this will work!